# Cant pass method to custom component jsf 1.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, tomahawk

I try to add action listener into my custom component.

I have custom datatable which wrapping tomahawk datatable.
I have custom dataScroller which wrapping tomahawk datascroller.
I need to pass into dataScroller method defined in datatable.

```
<custom:dataScroller actionListener="#{someBean['someMethod']}"...
```

or

```
 <custom:dataScroller actionListener="#{someBean.someMethod}"...
```

In taglib file:

```
    <tag>
        <name>dataScroller</name>
        <tag-class>java.lang.Object</tag-class>
        <body-content>scriptless</body-content>
     ...
        <attribute>
            <name>actionListener</name>
            <deferred-method>
                <method-signature>
                    void myMethod(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent )
                </method-signature>
            </deferred-method>
        </attribute>
     ...
    </tag>
```

in dataScroller.xhtml

```
<t:dataScroller id="scroller_#{for}" for="#{for}" 
                fastStep="#{fastStep}"   
                paginatorRenderLinkForActive="false"
                paginator="true" 
                paginatorMaxPages="10" 
                paginatorActiveColumnStyle="font-weight:bold;"
                renderFacetsIfSinglePage="#{allwaysRender}"
                binding="#{applicationBean.scroll}"
                actionListener="#{actionListener}"// HERE is the actionListener
                immediate="false">
```

this gaves me **`javax.faces.el.EvaluationException:` ... `Property 'someMethod' not found on type`** ...

It marks t he method as property but it should be marked as method

```
public void someMethod(ActionEvent sae) {
    LOGGER.info("Event: #0" + sae.getClass().toString());
}
```

Where should be the problem?